# Cannot register assembly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, c#

So I am trying to control Arcmap with my addin and I tried to add a command. So I did and i got this error:

```
    Error   6   Cannot register assembly "C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual
 studio 2010\Projects\ArcMapAddin4\ArcMapAddin4\bin\Debug\ArcMapAddin4.dll". 
Could not load file or assembly 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns, Version=10.1.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.  ArcMapAddin4
```

I changed nothing in the command code, this error just immediately appeared when I added it in visual studio. My question is, what am I doing wrong here and what does this error mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it doing this: Project -> Projectname properties -> Build and then disable:

"Register for COM interop"